# add _timestamp into index after creation for ttl to use it instead of index time

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, ttl

I am trying to enable the _timestamp field for my document type after creation of the index and after many documents have already been indexed to change the behavior of the ttl to delete based on the the _timestamp field instead of the index time.

My first question was whether such an addition to the mappings after creation at this point would have the desired effect?

Secondly, when I tried to add such a mapping

```
    curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping" -d'
    {
      "type": {
      "_timestamp" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "path" : "timestamp",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
   }'
```

I get the following error:
`Cannot update path in _timestamp value. Value is null path in merged mapping is missing`

I am unsure what the problem is since every document does contain the timestamp field

my existing mapping is:

```
{
  "events_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "events" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "notanalyzed" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "doc_values" : true,
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match" : "*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string"
          }
        } ],
        "_ttl" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "default" : 2592000000
        },
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "@version" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values" : true
          },
          "event" : {
            "properties" : {
               "event_hash" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "doc_values" : true
          },
          "geoip" : {
            "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "doc_values" : true
          },
          "user" : {
            "properties" : {
              "username" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed",
                "doc_values" : true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your complete mapping, please?

Comment: updated the question to include the complete mapping